# Python DataFrame problems

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, screen-scraping

I am doing some web scraping and making a csv with the scraped data.

I created a dataframe with columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'type', 'regular_price', 'Image src', 'Attribute 1 name', 'Attribute 1 value(s)', 'Attribute 2 name', 'Attribute 2 value(s)', 'Attribute 1 visible', 'Attribute 1 global', 'Attribute 2 visible', 'Attribute 2 global'])
```

I am looping over all my links and pulling data page by page and appending it to the dataframe with this:

```
df = df.append({'name':names,'type':'variable', 'regular_price':combprice, 'Image src':'1', 'Attribute 1 name':'Color' ,'Attribute 1 value(s)':'2' ,'Attribute 2 name':'Size' ,'Attribute 2 value(s)':sizes ,'Attribute 1 visible':'1' ,'Attribute 1 global':'1' ,'Attribute 2 visible':'1' ,'Attribute 2 global':'1'}, ignore_index=True)
```

I had all columns working except 'regular_price' and 'Image src', I did have 'Attribute 1 value(s)' Working. Although now it is not.

After each loop I am doing:

```
df.at[count, 'Image src'] = images
df.at[count, 'Attribute 1 value(s)'] = colors
```

Also the fact that 'regular_price' isn't being populated is weird because I can print the values with no issues, same with the 'images' list

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Append it to a df only once at the end, cache them in a list;

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the values into a dictionary when you iterate and create the dataframe at the end

```
dicts = {}
keys = ['name', 'type', 'regular_price', 'Image src', 'Attribute 1 name', 'Attribute 1 value(s)', 'Attribute 2 name', 'Attribute 2 value(s)', 'Attribute 1 visible', 'Attribute 1 global', 'Attribute 2 visible', 'Attribute 2 global']

for i in keys:
        dicts[i] = names # and others
```

Then at the end you an create the dataframe
`pd.DataFrame(dicts)`

Comment: Ok so I tried that and I am getting the same error I suffered from before. Its all arrays must be the same length when inputting data into the dataframe. The Sizes and Colors and Images are diffrent lengths due to the fact theres alot more values in those dictionaries. I was trying to use df.at to bypass that which did work for the sizes but it stopped working for some reason. Any ideas?